# mongoose get records that were created_at in the last 5 minutes using find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What's the proper way of retrieving the entries that were created in the last 5 minutes if I'm currently using Model.find()?

Answer (score 10):

Calculate the time of five minutes ago and then use the `$gte` operator:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-5);
Model.find({created_at: {$gte: d}}, callback);
```